# Hide app icon in dock when minimized

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I am new at Mac OSx development.

The app that I am creating requires removing the app icon from the dock throughout the application. The app allows minimizing and closing of the app window. Relaunching or reopening of the closed or minimized app window is done by clicking the app's icon from the status bar.

I was able to set the dock icon to be disabled during app launching; however, when the app is minimized (clicking the minimize button), it captures the image of the app's current window and adds it to the dock. I don't want that to occur. The app should not add any item to the dock.

Questions:

1. Does Apple allow removal of the app's re-launcher image from the dock when minimized?
2. If Apple allows this, how can I hide or remove the app from the dock?

Any help would be a big help! Thanks!

Comment: If your app doesn't go to the dock when minimized, how will the user ever get it back?

Comment: @Ken  The window usually minimizes to a separate section of the dock next to the trash.

Comment: Yes, and to get it back the user clicks that icon next to the trash.  Kimpoy is asking to not show that, correct?

Comment: @KenAspeslagh. Yes, that's what I want to happen. The user can relaunch the app by clicking the icon from the status bar (upper right of the monitor screen) that I have provided.

Comment: Sounds like you should disable minimizing as duskwuff suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable the display of a proxy tile when your window is minimized -- that's the primary way that users will restore a minimized window. If you'd rather that the window disappear entirely when it's not being used, disable minimization (in the window's flags) and have the user close the window instead.

Comment: I see...I was kinda hoping that it might be possible not to show the app in the dock and only allow the user to reopen the app window by clicking the app icon from the status bar of the monitor screen that I have provided. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Hiding the app in the dock is done using the LSUIElement Info.plist key.